# DisplayPort 1.2 DaisyChain with a DisplayPort to HDMI node at the end of the chain

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi, displayport

I recently bought a Dell monitor which has only DisplayPort and HDMI. and I was very excited to learn about the DisplayPort 1.2 daisy-chain. I was wondering if I could create a chain as follows

MacBookPro -> DP 1.2 -> Dell Monitor with Native DP 1.2 -> DP out from monitor -> DP to HDMI conversion -> Monitor with HDMI support.

Has this chain any drawbacks over a chain with native DP monitors? (Other than the end of the chain can't be extended anymore?)

Comment: So, does it work?

Comment: haven't tried yet. yet to find the correct cable. i ended up using HDMI from one end and DP from the other end of macbookpro at the moment. No external conversion adapters are used at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

If your monitor has both in and out ports for DisplayPort, then I think it is supposed to be possible.

The guy over at http://www.displayport.org/cables/driving-multiple-displays-from-a-single-displayport-output/ says that the final monitor in the chain can be a normal DisplayPort 1.1 monitor, and says that "next year" we should see hubs that would make it possible for all monitors to be simply DisplayPort 1.1.  (However, frankly, I'm not sure if he's trustworthy, because it appears that such hubs have been on the market for a few years now, and the only date on the article is 2015 at the bottom of the page as the copyright year, so, it *must* have been written *this year*, right?)

If you look at the specs over at http://www.startech.com/AV/Displayport-Converters/Mini-DisplayPort-Triple-Head-DisplayPort-Multi-Monitor-MST-Hub~MSTMDP123DP, you'll notice that they advertise that their hubs can themselves accept DisplayPort [1.1] adapters.

Basically, any adapter is supposed to be DisplayPort 1.1 compliant, and, it seems to follow, that you could thus use the DisplayPort 1.2 monitor (the one that has both in and out) just the same way as you would use a hub above.

Of course, these things are still novel enough that not many people have tried them, so, educated guess as above might not be correct.

Comment: Thanks for the insights, +1 i will accept your answer after some verification.  Much appreciated for taking the time to provide a response.

Comment: actually, it looks like your macbook might be a limiting factor, not supporting DP 1.2 -- you never mentioned which one you've got -- according to http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/169945/daisy-chain-of-two-dell-u2414h-to-macbook-pro-retina-13, only late-2013 and mid-2014 MacBook Pro with retina support DP 1.2; in case you have older graphics card, you'd only get mirroring from the daisy chaining (which might still be a great deal, depending on what you're after).