# Display Port 1.2 Daisy Chain with a DisplayPort to HDMI at last monitor

Tags: laptop, multiple-monitors, hdmi, displayport, daisychaining

I recently bought a Dell p2419HC monitor which has type C port to connect laptop then Display port out for Daisy chain , but my other monitor does not have display port, can I use below connection

My Dell Laptop -> Typ-C to Dell Monitor with type C -> DP out from monitor -> DP to HDMI conversion -> Monitor with HDMI support.

Thanks

Comment: This question should include more details and clarify the problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [DisplayPort 1.2 DaisyChain with a DisplayPort to HDMI node at the end of the chain](https://superuser.com/questions/866508/displayport-1-2-daisychain-with-a-displayport-to-hdmi-node-at-the-end-of-the-cha)

Answer (score 0):

According to [this forum post](https://www.dell.com/community/Monitors/Daisy-chain-last-using-DVI-D-VGA-HDMI/td-p/7698732) only if the DP to HDMI conversion is through an active component that does correctly handle the Display Port signaling.